# Parsing a txt file according to two different tags

Tags: text-processing

I need to parse a txt file like below. The part that needs to be parsed starts with "SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord" and text is between two parenthesis `{...}`. The key text length is not constant, so I can not parse it according to position. How can I parse and separate these line groups?

```
SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord

{

    recordType : '70'D
    chargingID : '306457009'D
    sgsnAddress
    {
        Address : 'FBDC'H
    }
    pdpType : 'F121'H
    dynamicAddressFlag : '1'D
    listOfTrafficVolumes
    {
        [0]
        {
            changeTime : '1412031353342B0200'H
        }
    }
    duration : '0'D
    causeForRecClosing : '0'D
    recordSequenceNumber : '1'D
    rATType : '1'D
    listOfServiceData
    {
        [0]
        {
            ratingGroup : '4'D
            resultCode : '4010'D
            timeUsage : '0'D
            timeOfReport : '1412031353342B0200'H
            failureHandlingContinue : '0'D
            serviceIdentifier : '404'D
        }
    }

}

SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord

{

    recordType : '70'D
    chargingID : '306457009'D
    sgsnAddress
    {
        Address : 'FBDC'H
    }
    pdpType : 'F121'H
    dynamicAddressFlag : '1'D
    listOfTrafficVolumes
    {
        [0]
        {
            changeTime : '1412031353342B0200'H
        }
    }
    causeForRecClosing : '0'D
    rATType : '1'D
    listOfServiceData
    {
        [0]
        {
            ratingGroup : '4'D
            resultCode : '4010'D
            failureHandlingContinue : '0'D
            serviceIdentifier : '404'D
        }
        [1]
        {
            ratingGroup : '4'D
            resultCode : '4010'D
            failureHandlingContinue : '0'D
            serviceIdentifier : '404'D
        }

    }
}

SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord

{

    sgsnAddress
    {
        Address : 'FBDC'H
    }
    pdpType : 'F121'H
    listOfTrafficVolumes
    {
        [0]
        {
            changeTime : '1412031353342B0200'H
        }
    }
    duration : '0'D
    listOfServiceData
    {
        [3]
        {
            ratingGroup : '4'D
            resultCode : '4010'D
            timeUsage : '0'D
            serviceIdentifier : '404'D
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the *sparse-files* tag? Did you mean *parse-files (if that is even a tag)*? A *sparse* text file is, by definition, not a text file at all, because a text file cannot contain `\0NUL` bytes...

Comment: What programming language would you want used to perform this parsing?

Comment: Does this representation have a name?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I need bash script or perl code. starts from the first occurence of 
SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord
{


till the last occurence of 
}

Comment: there are three parts in the text file, the output will be three different part of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command as following:

```bsh
awk 'NR!=1{print RS$0 >"file"i++}' RS='SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord' infile
```

- The `NR!=1` skips the first record which is empty.
- `RS='...'` defines `SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecord` as **R**ecord **S**eparator
- And the block `print RS$0 >"file"i++` saves the each record(`$0`) into 3 separates file with names `file0`, `file1` and `file2` (3 files in above OP's example input).
- `i++` used for incrementing the number of creation files.
- `infile` would be name of your input file to parse it with `awk`.

Comment: it does not work. result is below.

Comment: emmpre00:> cat file2
SASN2010Aber.CallEventRecord.egsnPDPRecordequenceNumber : '1'D
    rATType : '1'D
    listOf

Comment: @FatihTepekoy This works for me as well! Open the created files in graphical text editor. May be your terminal size is less than fitting the file content. the command works for me.

Comment: thank you for your help. I found an perl script, it works great.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

my $nr=0;
my $fh=undef;

while (<>) 
{ if ( m/^{/ )
  { open($fh, ">", "output" . $nr) or die "Can't open output file !";
  }
  elsif ( m/^}/ )
  { close($fh);
    $fh = undef;
    $nr++;
  }
  elsif ($fh)
  { print $fh $_;
  }
}